# Loading a Delphi XE4 project in older Delphi 2007 causes an error

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, delphi-xe4

I need to open a project written in Delphi XE4, but I have only Delphi 2007. When i try to open the project, I get this error:

> Only one top level element is allowed in an XML document

[image]

I know the error is due to the project is wrote in a newer Delphi version. Is there any trick i could use to open it in an old version ?

Comment: I would change the title to loading a project into an older version of Delphi, or something like that as it would be more meaningful.

Comment: You're most likely going to have a lot more substantial problems than this one trying to regress 7 or 8 Delphi versions (for instance, Unicode changes, units added/removed/reorganized, generics, compiler changes, etc.

Comment: Under Delphi 11.3 I have a similar error but when the dproj file is missing. I had to create a fake dropj file with the same name as the dpk file and then "fix" the entries of the dproj file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An XML document is required to have exactly on root element. The error is informing you that your document does not adhere to that rule and is thus malformed. That seems a little odd because no version of Delphi writes out such malformed `.dproj` files. Perhaps the `.dproj` file has been corrupted in some way.

The most expedient way to get around this issue is to remove the `.dproj` file and let the IDE regenerate one. From there you may need to apply settings that were previously set in the XE4 `.dproj` file, but you should at least be able to get started.

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me, as I downloded RealThinClient and first installed in my Delphi 11 and possibly I had saved it with Delhpi 11.

Later I tried to install it in Delphi 2007 and I encountered error. All I have to do was to delete dproj files and open dpk files and all went fine.

Later I found that older Delphi uses 2 spaces for indent in XML data while newer version use 4 spaces, thus old version wrongly interprates XML data if 4 spaces are used as indent.